# why select leads to high cpu sys load?

Tags: c, linux, performance, unix, network-programming

1. top: the cpu load of the process is 100%, and 90% sys
2. strace: all the system calls are **select**
3. select: **select(11, [8, 10], NULL, NULL, {0, 10}) = 0 (Timeout)**, fd 8 and fd 10 are both fifo
4. vmstat -n 5: the system cs and system in is very low
5. linux: 2.6.16.60
6. cpu: 4 cores, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5504 @ 2.00GHz

how to explain it? and i have changed the timeout of select to 1s, the cpu sys load changed to 85%, why?

**have changed nfds of select to the highest fd plus one, still high cpu sys load**

**EDIT -- Problem solved**
The bug has nothing to do with **select**, the third argument abstime of pthread_mutex_timedwait is **absolute time**, but i used **relative time** by mistake, which caused the high cpu sys load.
**And why pthread_mutex_timedwait causes high cpu sys load, not high cpu usr load?**
**strace: only see select system call, no others**

Comment: The first argument to `select` should be the highest file descriptor you have plus one, in your case, it should be 11, not 1024.

Comment: Indeed (man page) : *The first nfds descriptors are checked in each set; i.e., the descriptors from 0 through nfds-1 in the descriptor sets are examined*

Comment: @dreamlax I have changed the nfds to be the highest fd plus one, but the cpu sys didn't go better.

Comment: @ring0 I have changed the nfds to be the highest fd plus one, but the cpu sys didn't go better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a bad (disconnected) descriptor. Usually that is the main reason for such load on read `select`.

You may have data available, but never read it. Same situation.

You might do something really heavy between of `select` calls.

If your `select` always returns `0`, then the problem is not in `select` call. Its **elsewhere**.

Comment: @LtWorf have changed 1024 to 11, still very high cpu sys load

Comment: the cpu sys load is caused by system call, but according to strace, the only system call is select.

Comment: @pengdu: Why such a low timeout? You are almost better off sleeping and polling rather than timing out only after 10 microseconds...

Comment: @dreamlax set timeout to 1s, leads to the same high cpu sys load. :-(

Comment: @LtWorf Its elsewhere, not the select call's fault